# OrderBy Parent object by Nested Collection

Tags: linq

Simple

```
public class TimeLine
{
  public String Name {get;set}
  public List<Milestone> MilesStones {get;set}
}

public class Milestone
{
  public String Name {get;set}
  public DateTime Time {get;set}
}
```

I tried:
`from t in DataAccess.TimelineCollection.OrderBy(c=>c.MilesStones.OrderBy(z=>z.MilestoneDate)) select t;` but got an error that "At least one object must implement IComparable."

I need to order TimeLine by Milestone.Time.  First project in a list will be the one that has eraliest Time property in Milestone collection.

Need help with link.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It sounds like you might want

```
var query = DataAccess.TimelineCollection
                      .OrderBy(t => t.MileStones.Min(m => m.Time));
```

In other words, for each `TimeLine`, find the *earliest* milestone, and use that for ordering.

Of course if the milestones are in order, you could use:

```
var query = DataAccess.TimelineCollection
                      .OrderBy(t => t.MileStones.First().Time);
```

Both of these will fail if any `TimeLine` has no milestones.

Comment: Jon, thank you for you answer. Is there a way to check if TimeLine has no milestones and just put it on top?

Comment: `DataAccess.TimelineCollection                                        .Where(m => m.MilesStones.Count != 0)
.OrderBy(t => t.MilesStones.Min(m => m.MilestoneDate))
.Concat((DataAccess.TimelineCollection.Where(m => m.MilesStones.Count == 0)));`

Comment: @dotsa: You could use `.OrderBy(t.MileStones.Select(x => x.Time).FirstOrDefault())`